# Videojs PIP option not working in IE and Edge

Tags: video.js

I am using videojs plugin to play my Livestreaming URL.. PIP option is working fine in chrome.. but not working in IE and edge browser.. can anyone help me

Comment: Hello Priya, What I noticed is that you have asked a general question. In stack overflow you should ask questions that contain the steps of what you have done and the exact point in which the issue has occurred and mostly containing code or programming (Not general questions). You can edit your question or use other platforms of stack exchange network if you think your question is not related to coding. Wish you luck

Answer (score 0):

It won't work on IE and legacy Edge as those browsers do not support the Picture-In-Picture API. Chrome and Edge Chromium do support the API.